# get 10 comments for each answer by one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a comments table, like this:
`id`, `answer_id`, `content`

now i want to get latest 10 comments for EACH answer id.
list of answer ids are provided like (1,5,11,27,82)

is it possible to get all related comments by just one query ?

i currently do this by php's foreach:

```
foreach ($answers as $answer) { // query mysql for its comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` for each answer_id:

```
(select id, answer_id, content from comments where answer_id=1 order by id desc limit 10)
union all
(select id, answer_id, content from comments where answer_id=5 order by id desc limit 10)
union all
(select id, answer_id, content from comments where answer_id=11 order by id desc limit 10)
union all
(select id, answer_id, content from comments where answer_id=27 order by id desc limit 10)
union all
(select id, answer_id, content from comments where answer_id=82 order by id desc limit 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain in MySQL, but you can use variables:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             (@rn := if(@a = c.answer_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@a := c.answer_id, 1, 1)
                       ) 
             ) as rn
      from comments c cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @a := -1) params
      order by answer_id, id desc
     ) c
where rn <= 10;
```

This assumes that larger values of `id` are more recent.

Comment: @MehdiAzmoudeh . . . You can put a `where` clause in either query.  For performance reasons, I would put them in the subquery.

Comment: @MehdiAzmoudeh . . . This is a much more general approach.  Whether it is faster than another approach depends on your data, indexes, and perhaps other factors on the system you are using.